# Simple update query causes MySQL deadlock

Tags: mysql, deadlock

I have a simple table

```
CREATE TABLE counter (
id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
x_counter int(11) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

and a simple query

```
begin transaction
for (i=0 to 10)
    update counter set x_counter = x_counter + 1 where id = XYZ;
commit
```

When I run this query with same XYZ value (every process updates same row) from multiple processes no deadlock occurs (I think I did enough test to say it)

But when I do exactly same test, except use different XYZ values (every process updates different rows) I get deadlocks.

I have some idea about why it happens but I am not sure (not a db expert).

Can someone please explain what is happening here and how can I prevent it?

Thanks

Comment: If you wrap you statement in a transaction does the problem still persist. From what you wrote, there should be no lock escalation with only one read/write, especially in case 2.

Comment: Ross, query was wrong, updated it.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS;` showing the deadlock.

Comment: can you post the actual code that cause this?

Comment: @Barmar not reproducible. if the op code post the original code that caused this ...

Comment: Wait no part of the query is correct:
`Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'transaction for (i=0 to 10)     update counter set x_counter = x_counter + 1 whe' at line 1` and my MariaDB is MySQL Compatible as for starters it's `start transaction` not `begin`, `for` is also not valid in MySQL

Comment: @MartinBarker It looks like pseudo-code to me.

Comment: Maybe you have some trigger on update, that matches some condition that fires an update that triggers again ...